# SQL Select first that matches the criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a query where in I have to sort the table and retrieve the first value that matches for every id.

The scenario that I would like to achieve is to get the ID of Table A that matches the first ID_2 from the sorted Table B

I have a slight concept of the code.

```
select A.ID, A.COL1, B.COL1, B.COL2 
  from A, B
 where A.ID = B.ID
   and B.ID_2 = (select ID_2 
                   from (select ID_2 
                           from B B2 
                          where B2.ID = A.ID 
                       order by (case when B2.PRIO ...)) 
                  where rownum = 1)
```

The problem here is A.ID is not accessible within the select in where clause.

---

Another way that I found was using analytic function

```
select ID, COL1, COL2
  from (select A.ID, A.COL1, B.COL2, 
               row_number() over (partition by A.ID order by (case when B.PRIO ...) row_num
          from A, B
         where A.ID = B.ID)
 where row_num = 1
```

The problem with this code is I think it is not good performance wise.

Can anyone help me? =)

Comment: Statistic function? What does that mean?

Comment: Please show sample table data, and expected output.  What does "not good performance" mean? Please read [ask] for some tips.

Comment: @johngo `I think it is not good performance wise` ... why do you think that? Did you try running both queries against your data? Did you compare execution paths?

Comment: hi @Boneist, thank you for replying, this will be used for querying table / grid view in a website. Will the query be fast enough? =)

Comment: @johngo only you can test that. We don't have your data, servers, databases, etc. Try both versions and see which one works best for you.

Comment: I totally forgot about the execution paths, I will try it when I get to work, thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

`row_number()` is not a *statistic* function.  It is an analytic or window function.  It is probably your best bet.  I would do:

```
select a.*
from A join
     (select b.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by b.ID order by (case when b.PRIO ...) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
     on A.ID = B.ID and b.seqnum = 1;
```

If you really only want `A.ID`, then you don't need `A` at all . . . the information is in `B.ID` (assuming it is not being used for filtering). The above then simplifies to:

```
select b.id
from (select b.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by b.ID order by (case when b.PRIO ...) as seqnum
      from b
     ) b
where b.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: The join could be there to make sure only the rows in table b that have an id in table a are selected.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying, as Boneist said, the Table A is needed because I only need to show the rows that have the IDs in Table A. I'll try to check the execution path first, thank you for your answer =)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a correlated sub-subquery (which is invalid in Oracle), and you don't need an analytic function either. You need the aggregate `first/last` function.

```
... and b.id_2 = (select max(id_2) keep (dense_rank first order by case.....) 
                  from   b b2
                  where  b2.id = a.id
                 )     .....
```

Even this is probably too complicated. If you would describe your requirement (instead of just posting some incomplete code), the community may be able to help you simplify the query even further.